# Looking at values of individual points in a netCDF file with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, netcdf, netcdf4

I think that this question may be more not understanding an aspect of netCDF files rather than the netCDF4 python library.

I have data with several variables, some with several attributes. I want to filter the data based on the values of attributes in the variables. How do I look at the data point by point and copy the point to a new file if the attribute value meets my criteria?

Can I even look at the data point by point?

Comment: are you on a windows or linux system?

Comment: @AdrianTompkins Windows

Comment: it is just that this is really easy to do with CDO, but installing CDO (climate data operators) isn't easy under windows (e.g. see https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/wiki/Win32) - easiest with cygwin if you have that installed - otherwise there is a cdo package in python.  If you have CDO (or the python cdo) installed, you can do things like set up a mask that is 1 if a specific field exceeds a set value for example, and then use the mask to retain only the field values where this criterion is met - let me know if you are interested in this kind of  soln and I will post a full answer.